# Is there a way to have AB Pagination display P1, P2, P3 instead of P10, P20, P30?

Tags: add-on, pagination, ab-pagination

I am using AB Pagination to paginate news stories. When I click the numbered (and the next and previous) links, the URI segment is /P10, /P20, /P30. I would like the URI segment to be /P1, /P2, /P3. Does anyone know if this is possible? If so, how could I implement this?

Here is the channel entry tag I am using:

```
{exp:channel:entries 
    channel="news"
    disable="member_data|trackbacks"
    limit="10"
    sort="desc"
    status="open|featured"
}
```

and here is the pagination code I am using:

```
{paginate}
    <ol class="page-list group__title">
        {if abp_has_previous}
            <li><a href="{abp_previous_link}"><</a></li>
        {/if}
        {abp_pages}
            {if abp_is_current}
                <li><a class="is-active">{abp_num}</a></li>
            {if:else}
                <li><a href="{abp_link}">{abp_num}</a></li>
            {/if}
        {/abp_pages}
        {if abp_has_next}
            <li><a href="{abp_next_link}">></a></li>
        {/if}
    </ol>
{/paginate}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExpressionEngine uses the data from the pagination segment as an offset, not a "page number", per se. So even if you could change the values to P1, P2, etc, they would then yield incorrect results (if you wish to use EE's built-in dynamic pagination that is).

Answer (score 0):

Code Igniter framework actually enables such option:

$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;

and it works, but I don't know whether it's compatible with AB Pagination. If not, then well, shame on'em.